# React-native with PropTypes: Check Navigation params

Tags: react-native, react-navigation, react-proptypes

Es-lint keeps telling me that route.params is a missing dependency

I tried:

```
  route: PropTypes.shape({
    params: PropTypes.object.isRequired
  }).isRequired,
```

I also tried

```
  route: PropTypes.shape({
    params: PropTypes.shape({
      oauth: PropTypes.object.isRequired,
      set_oauth: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
    }).isRequired,
  }).isRequired,
```

Nothing seems to work, and I can't seem to find any help for this use case neither in ReactNavigation or PropTypes documentations

Comment: Are you sure the error is `missing`? Generally Eslint discourages the use of `PropTypes.object`, so that may be the error. Try changing it to `.shape({})`

Comment: Yes, it says: 'route' (and navigation) is missing in props validation (react/prop-types)